# Как разместить данные формы, используя javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте!

У меня имеется форма добавления материала на сайт. Она находится на странице add.html. Заполненные данные нужно разместить на странице index.html. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как обратиться к одной странице, находясь на другой. Я уже мозг себе сломал, в интернете не могу найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html

```
<center><img src="3195.gif"></center>
<br><br>
<iframe src="comm.html" height="270" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<br><center>Добавить комментарий: <br>
<iframe src="comm.php" width="187" height="161" frameborder="0"></iframe></center>
<br><br>
<center><a href="index.html">На главную</a></center>
<body link="black" vlink="black" alink="black"><br><br>
```

comm.php

```
<html>
 <title>Заголовок</title>
 <form action=enter.php method=POST>
 <form action="enter.php" method="post">
Ваше имя:<br>
 <input name="name" size="" value=""><br>
Ваш e-mail:<br>
 <input name="mail" size="" value=""><br>
Комментарий:<br>
 <input name="comm" size="" value=""><br>
 <input value="Добавить" name="enter.php" type="submit"><br><br>
```

enter.php

```
<?php
$name=$_POST[name];
$mail=$_POST[mail];
$comm=$_POST[comm];
$all = "&#1048;&#1084;&#1103;: $name 
&#077;&#097;&#105;&#108;: $mail <br>
&#1050;&#1086;&#1084;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;&#1072;&#1088;&#1080;&#1081;: <br>$comm <br><br>";
$file = fopen("comm.html", "a");
fputs($file,$all);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: @bazaev05, если хотите, чтобы ваши комментарии не требовали редактирования, форматируйте, пожалуйста, ваши ответы сами.

Answer (score 1):

Вам javaScript вряд ли поможет. Лучшим решением будет использование ещё и серверного языка. PHP того же.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать ajax, динамическую загрузку страницы и заполение формы. Правда, использовать серверный язык будет гораздо проще.